# What is the ideal way to handle data for front-end developments when using Tornado and AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, tornado

I'm building a Tornado Web application with AngularJS, and wondering is there a more elegant way to handle data from the server side. The case is that I want to pass data fetched from my MongoDB to the ng-controller.

The server side looks like this:

```
class MyHandler(BaseHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        list = yield db.data.find().sort([]).to_list(None)
        ...
        self.render("test.html", list=json.dumps(list), otherdata=otherdata)
```

And front-end side:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="obj in list">
        <td>{{! obj.a }}</td>
        <td>{{! obj.b }}</td>
        <td>{{! obj.c }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>


app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = JSON.parse('{{ list }}'.replace(/&quot;/g,'"'));
});
```

In my view, I think the this code is not good enough. What's your opinions about this ? How you guys handle this situation ? I will appreciate it if you can provide a better solution.

Comment: I would use the tornado template to generate the list items instead of angular, but LGTM

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks your opinion.